# Struct in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a struct class in Python and was wondering if this were a good way to write it:

```
class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if isinstance(getattr(self, key), str):
                setattr(self, key, value)

    def create(*args):
        newStruct = type("Struct", (Struct,), {"__init__": Struct.__init__})
        for arg in args:
            setattr(newStruct, arg, str())
        return newStruct
```

and to initialize the object:

```
myStruct = Struct.create('x', 'y')
variable = myStruct(x=2, y=4)
```

Also, is it actually worth using?

Comment: FWIW: https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy uses a "case" macro which is similar to what you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a mutable version of [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), with some oddities.

Following from your example (`myStruct = Struct.create('x', 'y'); variable = myStruct(x=2, y=4)`), I would expect `variable.z` to fail — and indeed it does raise an `AttributeError: 'Struct' object has no attribute 'z'`.  I would also like to see `variable.z = 5` fail with the same error, but it doesn't.  So, if it doesn't enforce what members can be set, what's the point of this object?  Why wouldn't I just use a regular `dict`?

The `__init__` function looks like a constructor, such that I would be tempted to write `myStruct = Struct('x', 'y')` instead of `myStruct = Struct.create('x', 'y')`) — but it actually doesn't work that way.  Also, I'd expect the constructor to work like `namedtuple`, accepting a `typename`, followed by `field_names` as either a list or a space-delimited string.

Defaulting values to an empty string is weird; I'd expect the default values to be `None`.  You can initialize the dictionary using [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys).

It would be nice to have `__repr__()` overridden, to make it easy to inspect the objects' contents for debugging.

### Suggested implementation

```
def Struct(typename, field_names):
    class StructType:
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            for key, value in kwargs.items():
                setattr(self, key, value)

        def __setattr__(self, key, value):
            if hasattr(self, key):
                super().__setattr__(key, value)
            else:
                getattr(self, key) # Trigger AttributeError

        def __repr__(self):
            return repr(self.__dict__)

    return type(
        typename,
        (StructType,),
        dict.fromkeys(field_names.split() if isinstance(field_names, str)
                      else field_names)
    )
```

Sample run:

```
>>> myStruct = Struct('myStruct', 'x y')
>>> variable = myStruct(x=2)
>>> variable
{'x': 2}
>>> variable.y
>>> variable.y = 4
>>> variable.y
4
>>> variable.z = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  …
AttributeError: 'myStruct' object has no attribute 'z'
>>> variable.z
Traceback (most recent call last):
  …
AttributeError: 'myStruct' object has no attribute 'z'
```

Comment: Thanks! I had originally thought that z=5 would not work.

Comment: `getattr(self, key)` seems needlessly cryptic. How about `raise AttributeError(key)` instead.